# Unable to perform data driven test using Apache POI

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

The line marked in star is giving error when the test is run in TestNG
Guys tell me what am I doing wrong in this.
I have attached the excel with 3 rows and 3 columns in 1st sheet.

Data lib code-

```
package Datalibrery;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

   public class Dataconfig {

      XSSFWorkbook WB;
      XSSFSheet sheet1;

    public Dataconfig(String Excelpath){



    try {
        File src=new File(Excelpath);

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

        WB=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

         sheet1=WB.getSheetAt(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }

}



public String getData(int  sheetno,int row,int col){

    sheet1=WB.getSheetAt(sheetno);

    **String data=sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();**

    return data;
}

public int getRowCount(int sheetindex){

    int row=WB.getSheetAt(sheetindex).getLastRowNum();
    row=row+1;
    return row;
}


}
```

Script Code-

```
  package SampleTest;

  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  import Datalibrery.Dataconfig;


    public class ContactusDDT {

       WebDriver driver;

      @BeforeTest

      public void beforeTest() {

      // If the browser is Firefox, then do this



          driver = new FirefoxDriver();


      // Doesn't the browser type, lauch the Website

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      }
@Test
public void login(){

    driver.get("Websit URL here");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='u157-4']/p")).click();// contact
}

@Test(dataProvider = "Contactdata")
  public void testLogIn(String Harshal1, String harshalb ,String Hi) throws Exception {





    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widgetu798_input']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widgetu798_input']")).sendKeys(Harshal1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widgetu783_input']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widgetu783_input']")).sendKeys(harshalb);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='widgetu791_input']")).clear();


  }

@DataProvider(name = "Contactdata")
public Object[][] Testdata()

{
    Dataconfig conf=new Dataconfig("C:\\Users\\harshadab\\workspace\\Sampledatadiven\\excelData\\Managemygrp.xlsx");
    int rows=conf.getRowCount(0);

    Object[][] data = new Object[rows][3];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        ***data[i][0]=conf.getData(1, i, 0);***
        data[i][1]=conf.getData(1, i, 1);
        data[i][2]=conf.getData(1, i, 2);


    }

    return data;
}
```

}

Comment: Harsha- It would be better if you- provide the error/exception stack trace in the post.

Comment: Could you edit in some information about the `getData` method? Siraj has a potential solution for you, but it would be better to validate that against the parameters he's changing.

Answer (score 3):

In excel sheet always start with 0-column and 0-row and index 0 as well.

Change

```
 data[i][0]=conf.getData(1, i, 0); 
 data[i][1]=conf.getData(1, i, 1);
 data[i][2]=conf.getData(1, i, 2);
```

to

```
 data[i][0]=conf.getData(0, i, 0);
 data[i][1]=conf.getData(0, i, 1);
 data[i][2]=conf.getData(0, i, 2);
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation for the change? When someone comes to this questions later, they'll want to know why it's necessary to change the values as you've suggested.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/9323)

Comment: @KatePaulk Given siraj's edit, I think this is a valid answer now. (Even if not correct... the two are different...) Would you agree?

Comment: @siraj It still could be more clear now, though. Are you suggesting that the sheet be zero indexed as well?

Comment: I'd agree it's a valid answer now although I would like to see more explanation.

Comment: my problem is solved. Thx

Comment: Harshal- Did this answer or aproach solved the problem. If yes you should go ahead and accept this as an accepted answer. Other wise add some explanation around your own solution.